# MongoDB Backup and Docker Problems

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, backup

I am weeks trying to do backup from my docker without any success.

My Docker Compose:

```
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: user
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - internal
    volumes:
      - /opt/rpg/mongo/data:/data/db
```

Input:    `docker exec mongo sh -c 'exec mongodump -d rpg --archive' > /home/rpg/all-collections.archive`

Output: `Failed: error getting collections for database rpg: error running listCollections. Database: rpg Err: command listCollections requires authentication`

Then i tried with password

Input: `docker exec mongo sh -c 'exec mongodump -d rpg —uri="mongodb://user:password@mongo:27017/rpg?authSource=admin" --archive' > /home/rpg/all-collections.archive`

Output: `SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.`

After weeks trying i get the connection with:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm --network internal mongo \
    mongo --host mongo \
        -u user \
        -p password \
        --authenticationDatabase admin \
        rpg
```

Now I can see the collections and everything, but i still cant get the backup.

Tried too:

Input:

```
sudo docker run --rm --network internal mongo \
    mongodump --host mongo \
        -u user \
        -p password \
        --authenticationDatabase admin \
        --db rpg
    > ~/rpg2-collections.archive
```

Output:

```
Failed: error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.
```

Without success, can someone help me ?

Comment: Have you tried `mongodump --db dbName --username userName --password password --authenticationDatabase adminOrAnythingElse`?

Comment: Yes i did. mongodump --db rpg --username user --password password --authenticationDatabase admin

Comment: and what was the result? I suggest you test your commands inside the container (using `docker exec -it mongo sh`) to bypass the possible problems with executing `docker run` and after finding the right `mongodump` command, try to run it from outside the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks, i get a backup from files (not mongodump).

```
sudo tar czvf /home/backup.tar.gz /opt/rpg/mongo
```

And i did a repair and worked at my pc.

```
 mongod --repair ./{{folder}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Was having the same Authentication problem, and this command worked:

```
docker exec <docker_container_name> sh -c 'mongodump --uri="mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/db_name?authSource=admin&readPreference=primary" --archive' > db.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it like this:

```
mongodump --host='{mongo_server}' --db='{mongo_db}' --collection='{collection_name}' --out={output_folder}
```

and it works just fine.
though as you can see i am doing collection by collection dump through python script on separate host, because i wasn't able to backup everything at once.

so the first step is to get all collections from container with installed mongo client:

```
mongo {mongo_server}/{mongo_db} --eval 'db.getCollectionNames()' --quiet
```

my script also uploads each collection dump to s3 bucket `s3cmd`, that is why you are seeing only part of it...

Comment: I keep with the same problema, Authentication.